# Python - How to use OpenCV2 and OpenCV3 at the same time

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I've always worked in my Python environment with the **OpenCV 2** library importing it with the common instruction:

```
import cv2
```

I now need to use features implemented in **OpenCV 3** and I therefore would like to install it without overwriting the existing OpenCV 2 version. The ideal thing would be being able to then write a simple script that is able to import OpenCV 2 and OpenCV 3 separately at the same time with something like:

```
import cv2 # Import OpenCV version 2 
import cv3 # Import OpenCV version 3
```

How would this be possible to accomplish?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: How are you installing python packages in your environment? Knowing that will help to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is possible. First install opencv3, and modify the `cv2` module folder name and the responding name in `__init__.py`. Then install the opencv2. So it won't overwrite the opencv3.

[image]

Step1: rename the folder name in `site-packages`:

> `site-packages/cv2` => `site-packages/cv3`

Step2: modify the module name in `site-packages/cv3/__init__.py`:

> globals().update(importlib.import_module('cv3.cv2').**dict**)

Step3: try to import it in your terminal ...

> import cv3